# Почему не удаётся собрать библиотеку Poppler?

Tags: c++, cmake, библиотеки, сборка

Пытаюсь собрать библиотеку Poppler из исходников при помощи cmake по инструкции от разработчика:

> Basic Installation: mkdir build; cd build;  cmake .. ; make; make install;

При выполнении команды cmake .. происходит такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл логов cmake и cmakelist библиотеки:

[CMakeOutput](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VPMFc9-1pDyDMyitimZ9GSGXHXZgfRqr/view?usp=sharing)
[CMakeList](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zg7c-BKBCV5y-s-NQEbkfMv-A2aq43_5/view?usp=sharing)

Информация о системе:

- Windows 11
- Visual Studio 2022
- Версия библиотеки Poppler: 22.01
- Версия cmake: 3.22.1

Пробовал собирать через Cmake Gui, результат тот же.

Comment: ¿А что получается, если выполнить команду `nmake -?` вручную?

Comment: Получается вот что:  `"nmake" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.`

Comment: Попробовал сделать сборку через командную строку Visual Studio, там nmake есть, но возникает другая ошибка:
`CMake Error at D:/Software/Programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Software/Programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  D:/Software/Programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:162 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:151`